# NodeJS Deployment to AWS Beanstalk errors

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've stumbled upon some issues when deploying to AWS beanstalk.
At first I thought the problem is with my Node.js app, but then I've tried clean install.
I've created blank Node.js Express app with WebStorm. Created new Application at AWS Beanstalk running on nginx 1.6.2
Then I zip my app and deploy it through Beanstalk console.
Upload completes successfully, however when I run application i get 502 bad gateway.
I've tried to change the default port since Web Storm creates app running on port 3000, so I've changed it to 8081. But i still get the error. When looking up for error in logs I've got the following.

**/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log**

```
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/app.js:8:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)module.js:340
throw err;

Error: Cannot find module '/var/app/current/routes/index'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/app.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)

module.js:340
```

It's clear that the problem is because node fails to find modules because of the relative path so I changed all entries with relative paths to use absolute path. for Example

```
var app = require('../app');
```

I've changed to

```
var path = require('path');
var app = require(path.join(__dirname, '../app'));
```

Still I get the same error.

Also I get the following error in nginx log:

**/var/log/nginx/error.log**

```
-------------------------------------
2014/12/05 14:28:35 [error] 23444#0: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.25.31, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "nodesampleapp-env.elasticbeanstalk.com"
```

Any idea why this is happening?
Appreciate any help.

Comment: could you find a solution for this ? @vladimr-novick

Comment: Nope. switched using AWS EC2 instance. I like it better. A little bit more initial setup, however you have full control of your instance.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, the node file name was wrong.

```
{
  "name": "your application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": 
    {
      "start": "node app_bot.js"
    },

    ...
```